# How to disable django.contrib.auth completely?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-syncdb

Because I'm using my own authentication and authorization system (with my own User/Permission model), I would like to completely disable this standard app from `Django`.

I've tried removing the relevant lines from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and
`INSTALLED_APPS`, but when I use the syncdb command, the default tables
that come with the default authentication system are still being
created. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? My main problem is that the standard tables are overriding the tables that I want to use for my own auth system.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'form_utils',
    'org',
    'auth',
    'entities',
)
```

I have also tried prepending the apps with the project package, this had no effect.

Is there maybe another setting that I'm overlooking? Other possible
variables that could cause these standard apps to be enabled despite
my efforts?

I also don't use the built-in admin system, so I don't think that
could be a problem.

Additional information: I have recently upgraded Django 1.2 to 1.3. Could this be the cause of my problem?

Edit: Apparently, this issue is caused by a change in Django 1.3. The related ticket is here: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15735

Any hints?

Comment: did you drop tables before ./manage.py syncdb?

Comment: I did, I even dropped the entire database for testing purposes. It just keeps creating the default auth_user table (while I want to use my own).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the authentication module is being pulled in by RequestContext.

By default, the setting TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS includes django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth.

I didn't have the issue of django creating the auth database tables, but it was inserting an AnonymousUser object into my context and my session under the 'user' key, even though I'd removed the auth modules from my INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES settings.

I removed that item from TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and things started working the way I had been expecting.

The upgrade from 1.2 to 1.3 in your case might have meant you started using class-based generic views (which are awesome), or perhaps you otherwise started using RequestContext instead of ordinary context dicts.  Either way, it seems that when auth is given as a context processor, django behaves as though auth were in your installed apps, whether you actually wanted it there or not.

I hope this is of assistance.

Comment: My apologies for accepting an answer so late, but thank you nonetheless :)

Comment: I wanted to remove Auth app as well, and after removing the middlewares I was still getting the error. Removed the entry from the template preprocessor in setting and everything runs smoothly now!

Comment: Is there any update for customizing the auth app now in a different way?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DRF, you will still have this problem.

Add These lines in your settings.py and it will solve the problem

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    /*

    */
    'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': None, # Needed once you disable django.contrib.auth
}
```

The problem is that the default value for UNAUTHENTICATED_USER is AnonymousUser (from contrib.auth). So if you don't set that setting to something else because you don't care to provide your own (likely, if you don't use auth) you will get this warning.