# Stripping down unnecessary apps from Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-database

I want to remove all the unnecessary apps that come as default while creating a project in Django.

My Project uses **Auth0** for **authentication** and **Firestore** for **database**. I don't want the default **database** app, the **admin** app and the **auth** app.

By following answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420918/run-django-application-without-django-contrib-admin), I have removed the **admin** app.

Now I want to remove the **auth** and the **database** app. Is there any way to do so?

Any suggestion about something else that I can remove from my project will be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already questions with answers for that here in Stack. More precisely,

- [Run app without django.contrib.admin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33420918/5675325)
- [Run app without django.contrib.auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024632/5675325).
- [Run app without database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4909072/5675325).

Also, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729150/5675325), there's a [Django Microproject](https://github.com/radzhome/django_microproject) with the bare minimum which you might find interesting.